# After Gradle Build, APK dont start to download on device: Errorcode

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

I got a problem: My app no ​​longer loads on my Smartphone. Until recently, it worked perfectly. But after I continue to program, the app no ​​longer loads on my Smartphone. Everytime i got an Errorcode (it goes on forever).

It would be nice if you would look into my logcat:

```js
2019-02-28 22:02:28.193 7490-26897/? E/SPPClientService: [Channel] Read error: ssl=0x75868d9c88: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
2019-02-28 22:02:28.199 7490-26897/? E/SPPClientService: [b] SharedConstants.WHAT_PUSH_NETWORK_NOT_AVAILABLE
2019-02-28 22:02:28.199 7490-26897/? E/SPPClientService: [b] ResponseMap empty
2019-02-28 22:02:28.210 7490-7490/? E/SPPClientService: [[PushClientService]] reqType : 0
2019-02-28 22:02:28.240 7490-7490/? E/SPPClientService: [[PushClientService]] F:false, D:false, E:false, T:false, S:true, R:false
2019-02-28 22:02:28.286 7490-7490/? E/SPPClientService: [[PushClientService]] reqType : 0
2019-02-28 22:02:28.298 7490-7490/? E/SPPClientService: [[PushClientService]] F:false, D:false, E:true, T:false, S:true, R:false
2019-02-28 22:02:28.800 7490-27507/? E/SPPClientService: [b] __InitReply__
2019-02-28 22:02:28.869 7490-27507/? E/SPPClientService: [a] onConnected Time : 2096565
2019-02-28 22:03:14.530 27534-27534/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2019-02-28 22:03:14.533 27534-27534/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 1
2019-02-28 22:03:14.554 27534-27534/? E/roid.themestor: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2019-02-28 22:03:30.346 3822-6184/? E/BartenderActivityManager: BarTender: pid : 26364 cached=true abnormal=false kill=false stay=false release=false
2019-02-28 22:03:30.590 26037-26085/? E/libmtp: [mtp_simple_sink_thread : 0315] -->[mtp_simple_sink_thread, 315] !!!!!! read failed errno [5], error [I/O error]
2019-02-28 22:03:30.590 24952-24956/? E/adbd: remote usb: read terminated (message): Cannot send after transport endpoint shutdown
2019-02-28 22:03:30.598 26037-26075/? E/MTPRx: stop observing and calling usbRemoved 
2019-02-28 22:03:30.603 26037-26085/? E/libmtp: [mtp_simple_sink_thread : 0363] -->[mtp_simple_sink_thread 363] read error [0] [Success]
2019-02-28 22:03:30.603 3456-3506/? E/DataRouter: USB Interface is open with 0x7
2019-02-28 22:03:30.628 26037-26075/? E/MtpMediaDBManager: updateMyfilesDB Count :0
2019-02-28 22:03:30.663 26037-26037/? E/MtpService: onDestroy.
2019-02-28 22:03:30.670 26037-26037/? E/MtpService: Unregister Mtp disable Receiver
2019-02-28 22:03:30.671 26037-26037/? E/MtpService: Receiver not registered: com.samsung.android.MtpApplication.MtpService$1@e69eb45
2019-02-28 22:03:30.672 26037-26037/? E/MtpService: Unregister mtpEmergencyReceiver
2019-02-28 22:03:30.672 26037-26037/? E/MtpService: Receiver not registered: com.samsung.android.MtpApplication.MtpService$2@526629a
2019-02-28 22:03:30.672 26037-26037/? E/MTPJNIInterface: noti = 103
2019-02-28 22:03:30.675 26037-26037/? E/libmtp: [__media_db_close : 4463] -->[__media_db_close:4463] media_sqlite_db is null 
2019-02-28 22:03:30.675 26037-26037/? E/libmtp: [mtp_usb_mtp_finalize : 1263] -->****** [mtp_usb_mtp_finalize 1263] mtp_close_fd Calling 
2019-02-28 22:03:30.675 26037-26037/? E/libmtp: [mtp_close_fd : 0118] -->[mtp_close_fd 118]  fd = 66...
2019-02-28 22:03:30.675 26037-26037/? E/libmtp: [mtp_close_fd : 0126] -->[mtp_close_fd 126] USB endpoint [66] closed...
2019-02-28 22:03:30.675 26037-26037/? E/libmtp: [mtp_usb_mtp_finalize : 1266] -->****** [mtp_usb_mtp_finalize 1266] Updating the gInitializeFlag Flag to FALSE 
2019-02-28 22:03:30.675 26037-26037/? E/libmtp: [mtp_usb_mtp_finalize : 1269] -->****** [mtp_usb_mtp_finalize 1269] Calling mtp_stop_io 
2019-02-28 22:03:30.705 3292-3926/? E/Sensors: inject_scontext_data: New ssp_data_injection_fd(32)
2019-02-28 22:03:30.735 3822-3846/? E/BatteryExternalStatsWorker: no controller energy info supplied for bluetooth
2019-02-28 22:03:30.909 3822-3960/? E/AlarmManager: No more alarm at this time. nowELAPSED=2158605 batch.start=2170070 mNextWakeup=2170070 mNextNonWakeup=2127697 mAlarmBatches.size=93
2019-02-28 22:03:30.909 3822-3960/? E/AlarmManager: Batch 1 size = 5 : 2170070, Batch 2 size = 1 : 2187696, Batch 3 size = 2 : 2223972
2019-02-28 22:03:30.909 3822-3960/? E/AlarmManager: No more alarm at this time. mNextWakeup will be set as zero : 2170070
2019-02-28 22:03:30.958 27660-27660/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2019-02-28 22:03:30.962 27660-27660/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 1
2019-02-28 22:03:30.979 27660-27660/? E/.devicesecurit: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2019-02-28 22:03:31.624 3822-3850/? E/UsbDeviceManager: getPersistProp return value is : persist.sys.usb.config
2019-02-28 22:03:31.663 27710-27710/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2019-02-28 22:03:31.666 27710-27710/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 1
2019-02-28 22:03:31.684 27710-27710/? E/.MtpApplicatio: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2019-02-28 22:03:31.885 27710-27710/? E/MTPRx: Unexpected Disconnection. call usbRemoved.
2019-02-28 22:03:31.889 27710-27710/? E/MTPRx: configured is false
2019-02-28 22:03:32.606 3456-3506/? E/DataRouter: USB Interface is open with 0x7
2019-02-28 22:03:32.830 4270-4820/? E/ImsAdaptorImpl: setSSACInfo : ImsAdaptorImpl.
2019-02-28 22:03:32.842 4270-4820/? E/ImsAdaptorImpl: setSSACInfo : ImsAdaptorImpl.
2019-02-28 22:03:33.283 3468-3582/? E/storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
2019-02-28 22:03:39.163 3822-4406/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 56 [2019-02-28 22:03:39.163] FD count : 516
2019-02-28 22:03:42.493 27731-27731/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2019-02-28 22:03:42.495 3822-3846/? E/BatteryExternalStatsWorker: no controller energy info supplied for bluetooth
2019-02-28 22:03:42.496 27731-27731/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 1
2019-02-28 22:03:42.536 27731-27731/? E/droid.sm.polic: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2019-02-28 22:03:50.791 3292-3926/? E/Sensors: inject_scontext_data: New ssp_data_injection_fd(32)
2019-02-28 22:03:50.795 3822-3846/? E/BatteryExternalStatsWorker: no controller energy info supplied for bluetooth
2019-02-28 22:03:53.045 3309-3345/? E/BufferQueueProducer: [[4306]#0] disconnect: not connected (req=1)
2019-02-28 22:03:53.064 27710-27710/? E/MTPRx: configured is false
2019-02-28 22:03:53.072 3822-4630/? E/WindowManager: win=Window{d8ac413 u0 com.android.systemui} destroySurfaces: appStopped=true win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=false win.mRemoveOnExit=false win.mViewVisibility=8 caller=com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.tryStartExitingAnimation:2737 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.relayoutWindow:2435 com.android.server.wm.Session.relayoutForTranslate:287 android.view.IWindowSession$Stub.onTransact:432 com.android.server.wm.Session.onTransact:186 android.os.Binder.execTransact:739 <bottom of call stack> 
2019-02-28 22:03:53.126 3417-3417/? E/audit: type=1400 audit(1551387833.121:283): avc:  denied  { search } for  pid=4270 comm="m.android.phone" name="android_usb" dev="sysfs" ino=26808 scontext=u:r:radio:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:sysfs_android_usb:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0 SEPF_SM-G950F_9_0001 audit_filtered
2019-02-28 22:03:53.127 3417-3417/? E/audit: type=1300 audit(1551387833.121:283): arch=c00000b7 syscall=48 success=no exit=-13 a0=ffffff9c a1=756c868260 a2=0 a3=0 items=0 ppid=3447 pid=4270 auid=4294967295 uid=1001 gid=1001 euid=1001 suid=1001 fsuid=1001 egid=1001 sgid=1001 fsgid=1001 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="m.android.phone" exe="/system/bin/app_process64" subj=u:r:radio:s0 key=(null)
2019-02-28 22:03:53.127 3417-3417/? E/audit: type=1327 audit(1551387833.121:283): proctitle="com.android.phone"
2019-02-28 22:03:53.207 27710-27710/? E/MTPJNIInterface: Getting CryptionKey from JAVA
2019-02-28 22:03:53.260 27710-27710/? E/MTPJNIInterface: noti = 17
2019-02-28 22:03:53.283 27710-27710/? E/MTPPlaObsrvr: inside setContext()
2019-02-28 22:03:53.284 27710-27710/? E/MTPPlaObsrvr: Inside registerContentObserver
2019-02-28 22:03:53.286 27710-27784/? E/MTPPlaObsrvr:  inside createplafiles
2019-02-28 22:03:53.299 27710-27710/? E/MtpService: onCreate.
2019-02-28 22:03:53.302 27710-27710/? E/MtpService: < MTP > Registering BroadCast registerBroadCastPolicyRec :::::
2019-02-28 22:03:53.309 27710-27710/? E/MtpService: < MTP > Registering BroadCast registerBroadCastEmergencyRec :::::
2019-02-28 22:03:53.315 27710-27710/? E/MtpService: onStartCommand.
2019-02-28 22:03:53.316 27710-27786/? E/MtpService: handleMessage. msg= { when=-1ms what=0 arg1=1 obj=Intent { cmp=com.samsung.android.MtpApplication/.MtpService } target=com.samsung.android.MtpApplication.MtpService$ServiceHandler }
2019-02-28 22:03:53.320 27710-27710/? E/MTPJNIInterface: < MTP > Registering BroadCast receiver :::::::
2019-02-28 22:03:53.323 27710-27710/? E/MTPJNIInterface: noti = 110
2019-02-28 22:03:53.324 27710-27710/? E/MtpService: onStartCommand.
2019-02-28 22:03:53.324 27710-27710/? E/MTPJNIInterface: noti = 102
2019-02-28 22:03:53.325 27710-27710/? E/MTPJNIInterface: setting Media scanner status0
2019-02-28 22:03:53.325 27710-27710/? E/MTPJNIInterface: After setting Media scanner status0
2019-02-28 22:03:53.326 27710-27786/? E/MtpService: handleMessage. msg= { when=-2ms what=0 arg1=2 obj=Intent { cmp=com.samsung.android.MtpApplication/.MtpService } target=com.samsung.android.MtpApplication.MtpService$ServiceHandler }
2019-02-28 22:03:53.328 27710-27784/? E/MTPPlaObsrvr: playlist count is2
2019-02-28 22:03:53.328 27710-27784/? E/MTPPlaObsrvr:  inside try branch createplafiles
2019-02-28 22:03:53.329 27710-27784/? E/MTPPlaObsrvr:  inside deleteing plas createplafiles
2019-02-28 22:03:53.329 27710-27784/? E/MTPPlaObsrvr:  inside deleteing plas createplafiles
2019-02-28 22:03:53.330 27710-27788/? E/libmtp: [check_media_scanner_status : 0523] -->Unable to get Object Class and clearing cls 2 [check_media_scanner_status 523]
2019-02-28 22:03:53.330 27710-27788/? E/MTPJNIInterface: Getting media scanner status0
2019-02-28 22:03:53.333 27710-27788/? E/MTPJNIInterface: DeviceName is Null in System
2019-02-28 22:03:53.336 5132-5132/? E/TrayManager: TrayManagerImp:trayMoveStart()
2019-02-28 22:03:53.337 5132-5132/? E/AppTrayPage: Cannot reloadForDisplaySwitch
2019-02-28 22:03:53.337 27710-27788/? E/MTPJNIInterface: DeviceName is Galaxy S8 von Salih Abi
2019-02-28 22:03:53.343 27710-27788/? E/SQLiteLog: (21) API call with NULL database connection pointer
2019-02-28 22:03:53.344 27710-27788/? E/SQLiteLog: (21) misuse at line 121756 of [0c55d17973]
2019-02-28 22:03:53.344 27710-27788/? E/SQLiteLog: (21) API call with NULL database connection pointer
2019-02-28 22:03:53.344 27710-27788/? E/SQLiteLog: (21) misuse at line 121756 of [0c55d17973]
2019-02-28 22:03:53.344 27710-27788/? E/SQLiteLog: (21) API call with NULL database connection pointer
2019-02-28 22:03:53.344 27710-27788/? E/SQLiteLog: (21) misuse at line 121756 of [0c55d17973]
2019-02-28 22:03:53.344 27710-27788/? E/SQLiteLog: (21) API call with NULL database connection pointer
2019-02-28 22:03:53.344 27710-27788/? E/SQLiteLog: (21) misuse at line 121756 of [0c55d17973]
2019-02-28 22:03:53.345 27710-27789/? E/libmtp: [mtp_init_device : 0726] -->[mtp_init_device 726]  After open the MTP fd = 66 and line = 726...
2019-02-28 22:03:53.345 27710-27789/? E/libmtp: [sua_support_present : 1319] --> [sua_support_present:1319] returning false 
2019-02-28 22:03:53.411 3309-3344/? E/NativeSemDvfsGpuManager: acquire:: Start
2019-02-28 22:03:53.411 3309-3344/? E/NativeSemDvfsGpuManager: acquire:: timeout = 1000 mIsAcquired = 0  mTagName : SurfaceFlinger 
2019-02-28 22:03:53.413 3309-3344/? E/NativeCustomFrequencyManager: [NativeCFMS] BpCustomFrequencyManager::requestGPU() 
2019-02-28 22:03:53.413 3309-3344/? E/NativeSemDvfsGpuManager: acquire:: End
2019-02-28 22:03:53.634 27710-27710/? E/MTPJNIInterface: noti = 13
2019-02-28 22:03:53.655 27710-27790/? E/SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 37516 of [0c55d17973]
2019-02-28 22:03:53.655 27710-27790/? E/SQLiteLog: (14) os_unix.c:37516: (2) open(/data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db) - 
2019-02-28 22:03:53.655 27710-27790/? E/SQLiteLog: (1) Process .MtpApplication : Pid (27710) Uid (1000) Euid (1000) Gid (1000) Egid (1000)
2019-02-28 22:03:53.655 27710-27790/? E/SQLiteLog: (1) osStat failed "/data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db" due to error (2)
2019-02-28 22:03:53.655 27710-27790/? E/SQLiteLog: (1) osStat failed "/data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases" due to error (2)
2019-02-28 22:03:53.655 27710-27790/? E/SQLiteLog: (1) Stat of /data/data/com.android.providers.settings : st_mode(40700) st_uid(1000) st_gid(1000) st_ino(1048832)
2019-02-28 22:03:53.655 27710-27790/? E/SQLiteLog: (1) Stat of /data/data : st_mode(40771) st_uid(1000) st_gid(1000) st_ino(983041)
2019-02-28 22:03:53.655 27710-27790/? E/SQLiteLog: (1) Stat of /data : st_mode(40771) st_uid(1000) st_gid(1000) st_ino(2)
2019-02-28 22:03:53.655 27710-27790/? E/SQLiteLog: (21) API call with unopened database connection pointer
2019-02-28 22:03:53.655 27710-27790/? E/SQLiteLog: (21) misuse at line 121756 of [0c55d17973]
2019-02-28 22:03:53.656 27710-27790/? E/MTPJNIInterface: Value of device_name is Galaxy S8 von Salih Abi
2019-02-28 22:03:53.754 27710-27790/? E/libmtp: [mtp_get_storage_ids_mtp_handle : 1396] -->mtp_get_storage_ids_mtp_handle : START !!
2019-02-28 22:03:53.844 27710-27797/? E/MtpMediaDBManager: count : 11207
2019-02-28 22:03:53.857 5132-5132/? E/TrayManager: TrayManagerImp:trayMoveEnd() stageMode: 2
2019-02-28 22:03:53.919 5132-5132/? E/TrayManager: TrayManagerImp:trayMoveStart()
2019-02-28 22:03:53.922 5132-5132/? E/AppTrayPage: Cannot reloadForDisplaySwitch
2019-02-28 22:03:53.960 3309-3636/? E/NativeSemDvfsGpuManager: acquire:: Start
2019-02-28 22:03:53.960 3309-3636/? E/NativeSemDvfsGpuManager: acquire:: timeout = 1000 mIsAcquired = 1  mTagName : SurfaceFlinger 
2019-02-28 22:03:53.960 3309-3636/? E/NativeCustomFrequencyManager: [NativeCFMS] BpCustomFrequencyManager::requestGPU() 
2019-02-28 22:03:53.960 3309-3636/? E/NativeSemDvfsGpuManager: acquire:: End
2019-02-28 22:03:54.223 5132-5132/? E/TrayManager: TrayManagerImp:trayMoveEnd() stageMode: 1
2019-02-28 22:03:54.753 27710-27797/? E/MtpMediaDBManager: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
2019-02-28 22:03:54.755 27710-27797/? E/MTPJNIInterface: noti = 29
2019-02-28 22:03:54.962 3309-5035/? E/NativeSemDvfsGpuManager: release:: Start
2019-02-28 22:03:54.962 3309-5035/? E/NativeSemDvfsGpuManager: release():: mIsAcquired = 1 , mName = GPU  , mTagName : SurfaceFlinger 
2019-02-28 22:03:54.964 3309-5035/? E/NativeCustomFrequencyManager: [NativeCFMS] BpCustomFrequencyManager::releaseGPU() 
2019-02-28 22:03:54.964 3309-5035/? E/NativeSemDvfsGpuManager: release:: End
2019-02-28 22:04:00.903 3822-3846/? E/BatteryExternalStatsWorker: no controller energy info supplied for bluetooth
2019-02-28 22:04:03.024 3822-4629/? E/BartenderActivityManager: BarTender: pid : 10049 cached=true abnormal=false kill=false stay=false release=false
2019-02-28 22:04:03.065 3822-4629/? E/BartenderActivityManager: BarTender: pid : 27413 cached=true abnormal=false kill=false stay=false release=false
2019-02-28 22:04:09.179 3822-4406/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 57 [2019-02-28 22:04:09.178] FD count : 516
2019-02-28 22:04:13.256 3822-4629/? E/BartenderActivityManager: BarTender: pid : 27731 cached=true abnormal=false kill=false stay=false release=false
2019-02-28 22:04:15.842 3822-4629/? E/BartenderActivityManager: BarTender: pid : 27534 cached=true abnormal=false kill=false stay=false release=false
2019-02-28 22:04:21.182 3822-4629/? E/BartenderActivityManager: BarTender: pid : 27660 cached=true abnormal=false kill=false stay=false release=false
2019-02-28 22:04:23.334 3822-4629/? E/BartenderActivityManager: BarTender: pid : 23348 cached=true abnormal=false kill=false stay=false release=false
2019-02-28 22:04:24.803 3822-6373/? E/BartenderActivityManager: BarTender: pid : 6005 cached=true abnormal=false kill=false stay=false release=false
2019-02-28 22:04:33.285 3468-3582/? E/storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
2019-02-28 22:04:36.325 3822-4629/? E/SemContext.CaeProvider: setAttribute() : attribute is null!
2019-02-28 22:04:36.345 3292-3926/? E/Sensors: inject_scontext_data: New ssp_data_injection_fd(32)
2019-02-28 22:04:36.400 27825-27825/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2019-02-28 22:04:36.403 27825-27825/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 1
2019-02-28 22:04:36.423 27825-27825/? E/ng.android.loo: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2019-02-28 22:04:39.197 3822-4406/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 58 [2019-02-28 22:04:39.196] FD count : 517
```

I have got a Samsung 8, with the newest Version 9.

Comment: when you click start on android studio what happens exactly?

Comment: when i click 'Run', i can select my Device(S8), or virtual devices.